# How utilize accessLevels with DNN

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

I´m using DNN7.0.3.

This is an example from my service controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Edit )]
//[DnnAuthorize(StaticRoles = "Registered Users")]
[SupportedModules("MyModuleName")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateWysUsersItem(BBWysUsersInfo item)
{
    BBWysUserProfileController controller = new BBWysUserProfileController();
    item = controller.UpdateWysUsersItem(item);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, item);
}
```

In ascx code behind I got the

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   DotNetNuke.Framework.ServicesFramework.Instance.RequestAjaxAntiForgerySupport();
}
```

When logged in as host (administrator) this service works and my table contents get updated. However when I am logged in as a "Registrated user" it fails with a "401 Unauthorized" message.

Replacing

```
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Edit )]
```

with

```
[DnnAuthorize(StaticRoles = "Registered Users")]
```

makes it work. However I don´t want this to work just for the Static role "Registered Users".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to bdukes at DNNChat.com. 
The error was me using

```
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.Edit )]
```

This will grant access to users who have Edit permissions to the MODULE!
However I do not want any other than admin to have this.

Thus the solution is instead to use:

```
[DnnModuleAuthorize(AccessLevel = SecurityAccessLevel.View )]
```

That´s all it is to it.
Simple when you know it.

Thanks @bdukes